# Xampp Apache crashing on startup

Tags: apache, xampp

I have just installed Xampp v3.2.1 onto my Win 7 Ultimate machine and Apache is crashing right after start up,

Here is the Log file:

```
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.299334 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.530347 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.569349 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.569349 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.569349 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:56.571350 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5180:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3004
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:57.313392 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3004:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:57.542405 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3004:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 07 11:46:57.583407 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3004:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads."
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, Need to run as Admin and adjust Anti-virus to allow Xampp to run, turns out I missed a step there.